# Script I can buy to display attachments inline like slideshare

Tags: php, document, documentviewer

Are there any scripts that I can buy to display pdf, ppt, doc attachments on my site - inline, so users don't need to download them to view it.

I run a knowledgebase which contains various documents uploaded by users - so trying to find a way to make it easier for them to view the files before download.

Google document viewer may work - but the terms of service does not allow us to build a preview application like slideshare. Anything else anyone has used to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Does your site run on wordpress ?
If yes,you can use the google doc embedder plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is presently any straightforward way to display, say, a .ppt in a browser; other than of course, converting it so as to be suitable for a flash player, or html5 player, as is SlideShare's case. I might however, be wrong on this.

SlideShare has a whole lot of document conversion architecture built on Amazon EC2 for the same. [Refer to [this post](http://engineering.slideshare.net/2011/05/suicide-workers/) on the SlideShare Engineering Blog].

Alternatively, there is [Zoho Viewer](https://viewer.zoho.com/home.do) - which is going to close down by the end of 2012. There was also PdfMeNot, but I don't think it exists anymore

Comment: So, no scripts then? The OP was asking for a script